# In eclipse for java Is there anything like Visual Studio Custom Debugger Visualizers

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

The ability to create custom debug visualizers for any .Net type in Visual studio is an interesting feature. Is there anything similar in eclipse for java objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't investigated VS debug visualizers enough to know whether it's an *exact* correspondence, but Eclipse does let you convert instances of given types into strings in a specified way for the sake of debugging.

See Preferences -> Java/Debug/Detail Formatters.

[Here's](http://web.archive.org/web/20100808063922/http://blog.jcake.com/2008/03/05/eclipse-debugger-part-i-detailed-formatters/) a blog post giving a walkthrough of an example. (There are plenty of others - a search for Eclipse and "detail formatters" will find loads. This one looked reasonable though.)

There's also the "Logical Structures" option in the same menu, and [another blog post](http://web.archive.org/web/20100808063157/http://blog.jcake.com/2008/03/09/eclipse-debugger-part-ii-logical-structures/) (the second part of the earlier one actually) with another example.

Edit 6.2 2012: Changed links to use archive since originals are no longer available.

Comment: Both links do no longer work as of Feb 06, 2012. The host still exists , but the blog seems to have been taken down.

Comment: @knb: Gah - deleted the links :(

Comment: Jon I was so free and reinserted the links but changed them to use the web archive instead. Hope you're fine with that :) (Not that useful without images, but better than nothing - useful thing I learned there, great!)

Comment: @Voo: Yup, absolutely fine by me :)